# how to capture user entered data in orbeon forms CE running through server into disk

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

how to capture user entered data in orbeon forms CE running through server into disk in any format like XML

Comment: Hi @surya, welcome to SO!  You might like to have a read of [the site's guidance on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and then explain [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have retagged this question properly. Not sure why mysql tag is added. I dont see anything related to database in your question

Answer (score 0):

First you can go through the introduction to Orbeon Xforms [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/orbeon-forms-xforms-tutorial#TOC-Orbeon-Forms-XForms-Tutorial).

Basically you can create a basic xform and the user entered data can be saved to hard disk, you can do that by creating a servlet which can store the stream content pushed by Orbeon xform and write it to a file.

Comment: thank u MR.kaipa , I'm using Orbeon CE and i have created a connection with mysql database with user as 'orbeon' can u please suggest me the code how to submit the form's values  into database.